# Normalizing image sizes based on batch average content dimensions?

Tags: image-processing, tensorflow, imagemagick, image-resizing

I have several thousand images of textual content that should be roughly the same font size and content block size.  The images were captured in such a manner that the actual content sizes are variable, but shouldn't be.  These images are trimmed so that all of the images have different dimensions, but in reality they should all have roughly an average of the same width (there are some margin notes, but they are relative outliers and wouldn't effect the content size in an unforgivable way).  The height is also fairly average except for, for example, chapter pages and "metadata" pages, so to speak.

I've considered a few options, but not sure which approach to take that will be both most efficient in terms of implementation while yielding an acceptably accurate output:

1. "Find" page numbers (bottom center of 99% of content) and
   calculate a resize ratio average and resize all pages according to
   their differential from the average.  Resize outliers with a general
   average differential that I track.
2. Use something like ImageMagick to track all of the page sizes,
   get an average and then just apply either a heigh or width average
   and preserve the ratio for the other dimension.
3. Or should I look more closely at something like TensorFlow?

Any thoughts on how to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Hard to suggest a solution without seeing an example image, but it sounds like OpenCV could be used to find the largest [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_rectangle). After which an affine transformation can be applied to normalize the dimensions, and TensorFlow's ROI-polling can scan for page number.